# [DJI-SDK][Android] NEW v3 SDK Demo is not working

Tags: dji-sdk

i downloaded the new SDK demo (v3) from github (https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android) and open the project with Android Studio (1.5.1).
 The import goes very well and all looks fine.

I changed nothing on the code or on the settings, except the dji app key, but when i'll try to start the application (on a Nexus 9 with Android 6) i get the following messages within the android monitor:

```
01-13 21:57:06.052 com.dji.sdk.sample I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-13 21:57:06.129 com.dji.sdk.sample D/FPVController: try to load libstlport_shared.so
01-13 21:57:06.132 com.dji.sdk.sample D/FPVController: try to load libdjivideo.so
01-13 21:57:06.139 com.dji.sdk.sample E/linker: /data/app/com.dji.sdk.sample-1/lib/arm/libdjivideo.so: has text relocations
01-13 21:57:06.139 com.dji.sdk.sample E/FPVController: Couldn't load lib
01-13 21:57:06.192 com.dji.sdk.sample E/art: No implementation found for int dji.midware.natives.FPVController.native_init(java.lang.Object) (tried Java_dji_midware_natives_FPVController_native_1init and Java_dji_midware_natives_FPVController_native_1init__Ljava_lang_Object_2)
01-13 21:57:06.192 com.dji.sdk.sample D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-13 21:57:06.199 com.dji.sdk.sample W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DJI/com.dji.sdk.sample/LOG/CRASH/crash-2016-01-13-21-57-06.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-13 21:57:06.199 com.dji.sdk.sample W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
01-13 21:57:06.199 com.dji.sdk.sample W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
01-13 21:57:06.199 com.dji.sdk.sample W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:127)
01-13 21:57:06.199 com.dji.sdk.sample W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:116)
01-13 21:57:06.199 com.dji.sdk.sample W/System.err:     at dji.publics.b.f.b(Unknown Source)
01-13 21:57:06.199 com.dji.sdk.sample W/System.err:     at dji.publics.b.f.a(Unknown Source)
01-13 21:57:06.199 com.dji.sdk.sample W/System.err:     at dji.publics.b.f.uncaughtException(Unknown Source)
01-13 21:57:06.199 com.dji.sdk.sample W/System.err:     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
01-13 21:57:06.199 com.dji.sdk.sample W/System.err:     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
01-13 21:57:06.199 com.dji.sdk.sample W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-13 21:57:06.199 com.dji.sdk.sample W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
01-13 21:57:06.199 com.dji.sdk.sample W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
01-13 21:57:06.199 com.dji.sdk.sample W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
01-13 21:57:06.199 com.dji.sdk.sample W/System.err:  ... 8 more
01-13 21:57:06.200 com.dji.sdk.sample E/DJICrashHandler: uncaughtException 2
01-13 21:57:06.200 com.dji.sdk.sample E/DJICrashHandler: uncaughtException 3
01-13 21:57:06.226 com.dji.sdk.sample I/onLoad: loaded onLoad.cpp :JNI_OnLoad() go to end
01-13 21:57:06.226 com.dji.sdk.sample D/GroudStation: load lib suc
01-13 21:57:06.234 com.dji.sdk.sample D/DJIGimbalParamInfoManager: readToMemory size = 19
01-13 21:57:06.300 com.dji.sdk.sample D/DJIFlycParamInfoManager: readToMemory size = 583
01-13 21:57:06.401 com.dji.sdk.sample E/DJICrashHandler: uncaughtException 4
01-13 21:57:06.402 com.dji.sdk.sample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                     Process: com.dji.sdk.sample, PID: 3145                                                       java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int dji.midware.natives.FPVController.native_init(java.lang.Object) (tried Java_dji_midware_natives_FPVController_native_1init and Java_dji_midware_natives_FPVController_native_1init__Ljava_lang_Object_2)
                                                         at dji.midware.natives.FPVController.native_init(Native Method)
                                                         at dji.midware.data.manager.P3.ServiceManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                         at dji.midware.data.manager.P3.ServiceManager.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                         at dji.sdk.SDKManager.DJISDKManager.initParams(Unknown Source)
                                                         at dji.sdk.SDKManager.DJISDKManager.initSDKManager(Unknown Source)
                                                         at com.dji.sdk.sample.common.DJISampleApplication.onCreate(DJISampleApplication.java:71)
                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4707)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-13 21:57:31.447 com.dji.sdk.sample I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13145 SIG: 9
```

and the app will be closed directly on the android tablet.
 Can anybody help me and tell me what im doing wrong? And why it is not possible to just download and start the sdk demo?

Thanks in advance!
 Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was the Android version within the App, because the SDK Lib is build with android level 22 and the app was build with android level 23.

After reducing the app to version 22 the app is working!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Identification Code when you apply for the App Key on [DJI Developer User Center](http://developer.dji.com/en/user/apps/), it should be **com.dji.sdk.sample**. For more info, please check the [DJI Android SDK Github Page](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android), you can follow the guides there. Hope this help!